# Generating .po/.mo files

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, localization, internationalization

I have a database full of translations I'd like to generate either .po or .mo files. I'm using C#, but I could also port an implementation from PHP if one exists. I can't find any examples in any languages using anything other than GNUs gettext utilities. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the spec it looks to be a fairly simple format. Not as pretty as XML but at least every element starts with a unique sequence.

Answer (score 1):

the .po files are really easy to generate you could use poedit. When all the strings are (non translated) are in the file write a script which goes through the database searches for the msgid and then copies the msgstr from the database into the .po file. After the .po file is done save it and poedit creates a .mo file for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't create .po files using POEdit? How to do that? There is a path that starts with . when choosing "New catalogue" but what should be in that path?